# Ubuntu inaccessible in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu desktop in Oracle VirtualBox and it suddenly says that it is inaccessible from last login

```
The given path '{c2545323-feb8-4b7b-ab00-d4c9c8eb2a85}' is not fully qualified.

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Callee RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

In the root there is only `ubuntu.vbox-prev` file and `ubuntu.vbox` file.

I have important files in it. How can I regain access?

[image: VirtualBox error]

Comment: This seems like a question about the Virtualbox application on your Host (whatever OS that is). Were the problem with the Ubuntu Guest, it would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for the edit I'll follow up  that way buy the way I have done with it too someone want to know will tell you